# What is the use of role when registering user in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

fabric_ca_client.register({enrollmentID: 'user', affiliation: 'org1',***role: 'client'***}, admin_user)

Answer (score 1):

In your business model, for example a restaurant, you can have a chef, a waiter, an administrator, etc, these should be their roles. During a transaction execution, you can check the role of the user inside the chaincode, for example, a chef can cook, if any other user that its not a chef invoke the transaction cook(), this transaction would not be going.
Also, for endorsing policy, a peer identity, should have one of this roles:

- client
- member
- admin
- peer

You can check more [here.](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/endorsement-policies.html#endorsement-policy-syntax)